# ¿Cómo puedo leer una celda de Google Spreadsheet desde Slack?

Tags: slack-api

¿Cómo puedo verificar los resultados de mi hoja de cálculo de Slack usando los comandos de barra oblicua?

Estoy trabajando con 2 personas, llenan su venta diariamente en una hoja de cálculo de Google, y quiero comprobar la columna ventas para ver cuántas ventas hizo cada persona.

Estoy usando Google Apps Script, para crear una aplicación web compruebe la columna y envíeme un resultado a la holgura.

Sigo, este [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456429/configure-google-apps-script-callback-for-slack-slash-command) y está funcionando, pero no sé cómo extraer los datos de la hoja de cálculo.

Comment: Hola @jvera... Estamos recibiendo varias preguntas en inglés. Realmente me preguntaba, si podrías aclarar, ¿Qué te llevó a preguntar en inglés acá?

Comment: Puse stackoverflow pero me redireccionó a la versión en español y mi pregunta ya la tenía hecha en google translate (de es a en) y solo copié y pegue... como las 2 páginas sin iguales, no me di cuenta.